# SQL Reporting services, parameter value update not showing

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

We have a single report that has about 100 linked reports based off it. One of the parameters of the report has just had another option added to it. We've uploaded the new report to overwrite the old one.
The problem is the new parameter value is not available in any of the linked reports.

The only way to make it available seems to be to delete the report and recreate it which makes the option appear but means you lose subscription/security settings etc which makes it a no go to do for all reports.

Does anyone know another way around it?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before doing anything backup the report server database.

Do a select to the report database

```
select *
from dbo.Catalog
where name like N'report_name'
```

In the result set, in column type you can see values 2 and 4.

Value 2 is the original report and value 4 is a linked report.

Note down the original report id as is needed next for the update

```
update c2
set c2.parameter = c1.parameter
from dbo.Catalog c1
join dbo.Catalog c2 ON c1.itemId = c2.LinksourceId
where c1.itemid -- the original report's id
```

Comment: Haven't had chance to try it yet but it looks ideal, thank you!